# Running a bash script as nrpe user fails

Tags: linux, bash, redhat-enterprise-linux, nagios

I created a bash script that is supposed to search inside all log folders on multiple servers, and compress all the log files on rpm based machines (RHEL and Centos 6 & 7 servers).
The script is supposed to create a lockfile to prevent multiple instances of it running, and the entire script, which makes a lot of use of find and tar, and rm commands, is supposed to be run by the nrpe user with sudo powers, when a Nagios event handler is triggered.

I have granted the sudo permissions to nrpe in order to run this command, but I noticed that when I try to run the script there are permissions denied:

```
sudo -u nrpe /share/username/run/fixstorage.sh
touch: cannot touch `/var/run/fixstorage.lockfile': Permission denied
find: `/var/log/sssd': Permission denied
find: `/var/log/salt': Permission denied
find: `/var/log/httpd': Permission denied
find: `/var/log/audit': Permission denied
```

But then the script appears to continue running but without any output. 
And storage is not fixed.
How can I get nrpe to run the entire script properly?
The permissions on the script is:

```
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 username username 5516 Jan  3 23:36 /share/username/run/fixstorage.sh
```

Its in a user's home folder which is NFS mounted.

Comment: Does the nrpe user have write permissions on the first file and read permissions on the directories? I doubt that he has. What you have basically done is just run the script as user nrpe without giving him any extra privilages.

Comment: The nrpe user has permission to run the script as root. Isn't that supposed to be sufficient ?

Comment: That should be enough yes, just to check that could you please add to the question the output of `ls -l /share/username/run/fixstorage.sh`.

Comment: Done. 
I wonder why people are dropping points from my question. Is it too stupid or something? That is massively petty behavior. If I knew what I was doing I wouldn't ask.

Comment: From what I see here then the script is not run with root privilages, if you really want to run it with root privilages then use the suid bit on the script file.

Comment: Well, suid could be a security problem. Why not run the script as root directly? Just use `sudo /share/username/run/fixstorage.sh`?

Comment: Thats exactly how I am running the script in nrpe:
`command[fix_storage]=/usr/bin/sudo /share/username/run/fixstorage.sh`
but I now see a mistake: sudo is in /bin not /usr/bin on rhel7.
I might just try setting the suid bit. Thanks!